# How to recover Ubuntu from windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I was dual booting successfully for the last week with no issues at all. But I wanted to try using the Burg grub menu, so on a different drive, in installed Windows 10, then Ubuntu to test that it wouldn't break anything. It worked on that drive. But as soon as I hooked my main drive up again, it didn't show a grub menu and went straight to windows 10. Is there any way to fix this or get the iso of Ubuntu at least and reinstall it?

Any ideas of what could have possibly happened so I can prevent this in the future? Or is it just not possible to dual boot reliably?

I've checked that fast boot is turned off on windows 10.

Comment: Set your bios to boot from the drive where you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I just figured it out. Ubuntu and Windows are installed on the same drive. But in the bios (MSI) if I go Settings > Boot > UEFI Hard Disk BBS Priorities. There's a boot option #1 and #2. Every time I disconnect the SSD, it sets windows back to #1. Which skips the GRUB screen.